# Is there a drag in a moving fluid due to pressure (reaction) from the walls of the tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, flow, bernoulli-equation, viscosity

Consider a tube of linearly varying cross section... Now consider a section of the tube...There are pressure on the ends of this section due to the fluid...  Now consider the walls, there is a pressure perpendicular to the walls and thus a reaction pressure(or force say). Now divide the forces into their horizontal and vertical components... We see that the vertical components cancel out because there is no net vertical motion of the liquid... But the horizontal forces remain unbalanced. Will not they act as kind of drag force thus resisting the motion of the liquid...(consider the liquid is flowing in the direction opposite to the forces)

And if this is true why dont we consider them while calculating Bernoulli's Equation...? We only consider the forces at the ends.

*Consider laminar flow*

Comment: The Bernoulli equation neglects viscous drag.  Viscous drag is related the the effect of the fluid velocity increasing with distance from the wall, causing a viscous shear force on the fluid by the wall.  The Bernoulli equation is not the be-all and end-all for everything.

Comment: But the viscous drag is all about friction... what I am asking here is actually due to the pressure... it isn't a kind of a viscous drag...

Comment: Viscous drag is not mechanistically about friction (at least not the dry friction you may be thinking of).  The drag has nothing to do with pressure, which acts normal to the wall. I don't think you understand how viscous drag works.

Comment: I know viscous forces are due to the interactions(adhesive) between the liquid molecules and the solid... And then there are the cohesive forces which transfer the adhesive effects...isn't it...

Comment: Not exactly.  The axial momentum of the fluid molecules is being reduced by collisions with slower axially moving molecules closer to the wall.  So molecules exchange axial momentum by radial collisions.  The molecules at the wall have zero axial organized momentum because of the so called no-slip boundary condition.  For more details on this mechanistic picture, see Chapter 1 of Transport Phenomena by Bird et al.

Comment: O... thanks for the information, i didn't know the details... we are just introduced with the topic in high school, so that's why... I would certainly like to read your suggested book... Thanks Glad you answered.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli Equation has been formed considering fairly ideal conditions. A "non-viscous and homogenous" liquid was taken in a laminar flow as you mentioned. Friction along the sides of the tube was considered to be negligible. However, in real world scenario no fluid can be truly non-viscous and there will be some drag.

The point is, you can get a fairly accurate estimates even if you ignore the drag there.
The horizontal force will obviously play the part of actually moving the liquid.

Comment: So are you talking about viscous drag... or you are also indicating to the type of drag I have mentioned... drag due to pressure... I think you are pointing to both, right?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes what we need from physics is 'fairly accurate' estimates. Therefore, to avoid unnecessary complication the drag forces have been neglected altogether. Also drag is NOT due to pressure. The excess pressure propels the liquid forward.

Comment: Ok thanks Brother....